# Given that $f'(0) = f''(0) = 1$, $f^{(12)}$ exists, and $g(x)= f(x^{10})$. Find $g^{(11)}(0)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $f'(0) = f''(0) = 1$, $f^{(12)}$ exists, and $g\colon x \mapsto f(x^{10})$. Find $g^{(11)}(0)$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Chain rule?

Comment: Look at an example, say, $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} +x +1$, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By chain rule, we have 
$$g'(x) = 10f'(x^{10})x^9$$
and by product rule and chain rule 
$$g''(x) = 10\times 10f''(x^{10})x^9x^9+10\times 9f'(x^{10})x^9 = 100x^{18}f''(x^{10}) + 10\times9f'(x^{10})x^9$$
Since $g^{(11)}(x)$ will be evaluated at $x=0$, the first term can be discarded directly considering the exponent grows for each differentiation. 
Continuing, you will get
$$g^{(10)}(x) = \text{loads of discarded terms} + 10\times9 \times \dots\times 2 f'(x^{10})$$

Now calculate $g^{(11)}(x)$ and set $x=0$ to get the result.

(Side note: We have used the fact that $f^{(12)}(x)$ exists in the discarded terms above, since this implies that all derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$ for $n < 12$ also exist.)

Answer (score 1):

Given any $t\mapsto f(t)$ defined in a neighborhood $\ ]{-h},h[\ $ of $t=0$ the function
$$g(x):=f\bigl(x^{10}\bigr)\qquad\bigl(|x|<h'\bigr)\tag{1}$$
is even, and if $f$ is sufficiently differentiable at $0$ one necessarily has $g^{(11)}(0)=0$: Since $g(x)=g(-x)$ for all $x$, by the chain rule one has $g^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k g^{(k)}(-x)$ for all $k\geq0$, which implies $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for odd $k$.

For an approach that does not make use of the special situation at hand assume for simplicity that $f\in C^\infty$. Then by Taylor's theorem we may write
$$f(t)=f(0)+t+{t^2\over2}+t^3 f_1(t) \qquad\bigl(|t|<h\bigr)$$
with $f_1\in C^\infty$. It follows from $(1)$ that
$$g(x)=f(0)+x^{10}+{x^{20}\over 2}+x^{30}f_1\bigl(x^{10}\bigr)\ .$$
Here one can read off that all $g^{(k)}(0)$ for $k\in[1,29]\setminus\{10,20\}$ are $=0$.

Comment: For which $n$ does it hold that $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$? I get that $g^{(10)} = 10!$ and $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ otherwise, but I'm probably wrong (see my answer below).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How do you conclude your first sentence without going through the general case (or similar calculations)? Would you say it is obvious enough that it would suffice as an answer to an exercise? (I'm asking because it's not very obvious to me, but I am on the other hand no maths student let alone mathematician.)

Comment: Ah, that's a nice motivation (+1). Thanks Christian!

Answer (score 0):

By [Faa di Bruno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) we have
$$
 g^{(11)}(x) = \sum_{\substack{m_j \ge 0\\ m_1 + 2m_2 + \cdots + 11m_{11} = 11}} \frac{11!}{m_1!1!^{m_1} \cdots m_{11}!11!^{m_{11}}}f^{(m_1 + \cdots + m_{11})}(x^{10})\prod_{j=1}^{11} \bigl((x^{10})^{(j)}\bigr)^{m_j}
$$
Noting that $(x^{10})^{(j)}|_{x=0} = 0$ when $j \ne 10$, only those summands with $m_j = 0$ for $j \ne 10$ are $\ne 0$ at $x=0$. But for any non-negative $m_j$ with $m_1 + \cdots + 11m_{11} = 11$ we must have $m_j > 0$ for some $j \ne 10$. Hence $g^{(11)}(0) = 0$.